# Mark one of the columns not to sync with server using Azure App service offline data sync

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Is there a way I can have one column only on device? i.e. the column should only always exist in the device & never on the server.

If I mark the property in the class with [JsonIgnore] will that do the trick?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

creating a new property in my class only visible to the client app (Xamarin forms) did the trick.

Thanks